# Backbone Collection Fetch with other model condition

Tags: backbone.js, collections, fetch

Attention Everyone,

I am now trying to solve collection fetch odd problem.

What I want is to fetch Tabs collection and speaking of DB, Tabs Table has an association with Record Table.
So if the record table decides which tabs are enable while other tabs are disable, how can fetch only enabled tabs?

To clarify everything, now I add two table structures.

> Tab
>
> id:integer title:string, content:string
>
> Record
>
> id: integer, ... , tabs_value:integer

here, the binary expression of tabs_value decides which tabs are enable while other tabs are disable.

I hope to know it soon.

PS: You know record id already, namely, you know which record is using for this fetch.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not setting the enabled/disabled state on the tab itself?

Comment: Yeah, by some reason, the enable/disable status is not in tab table, but record table.